# In Python, how to initialize a class attribute from the return value of a class method?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

Imagine we have this class:

```
class Custom:
    @classmethod
    def get_choices(cls):
        # use cls attributes to return a list

    mapping = {"key": ... }
```

I would like to associate the value returned by `get_choices()` to `key`. What code should go instead of the placeholder `...` ?

---

**EDIT:** I wanted to keep the question context-agnostic (it seemed to me that this requirement was common enough, but I could be biased). As was suggested in comments, I will give some more details, because it seems we share the concern of 'most straightforward code':

I am working on a Django application, where I want to keep *enumeration* of values separated of the `Model`s using them. What seemed to me like a natural solution was to create an *enumeration.py* module, where I could then define a `class` for each enumeration (the class having at least a class method to *generate* the collection of values). This is the `get_choices()` in the example.

Now, because of business logic, I need to map those choices to a key. This mapping being logically coupled to the enumeration, it seemed like a good structure to keep them together, in the same class (giving client code uniform and explicit access, being prefixed by the class name).

Comment: You cannot do that within the class, `@classmethod`s are not actually callable until after that class definition is completed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Who would have guessed C++ was spoiling its users with conveniences not to be found in Python ;)

Comment: That does seem unlikely! I answered a tangentially-related question yesterday, you may find my answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32069776/3001761

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do it in class definition because class object has not been created yet.
After the class definition, you could definitely do something like this -

```
Custom.mapping['key'] = Custom.get_choices()
```

Although the recommended way to do this would be to use a metaclass.

```
class CustomMetaClass(type):

      def __init__(cls, classname, bases, attrs):
          super(CustomMetaClass, cls).__init__(classname, bases, attrs)

          cls.mapping['key'] = cls.get_choices()

class Custom(metaclass = CustomMetaClass): # assuming you are using python 3

      mapping = {}

      @classmethod
      def get_choices(cls):
          # add your custom code here
          pass
```

With that said, that is an Object Oriented solution to the problem. you can ofcourse use some function to generate choices thus ending the need to use metaclass.

## For Edited Question:-

In that case, I think you should just maintain a file named 'choices.py' as you yourself suggested and use them in your mapping, instead of `get_choices` class method. You don't need to unnecessarily make classes for each model if all you want to do is store choices. Just use dicts and constants.

If your classes needs to be generated dynamically, say from db, then you need to create separate model for storing choices.

```
class CustomModelChoices(models.Model):

      model_name = models.StringField(db_field = 'mn')
      choices = models.DictField(db_field = 'ch')

class CustomModel(models.Model):

     _choice_generator = CustomModelChoices

     mapping = {
         'key': CustomModelChoices.objects.get(model_name = 'CustomModel').choices
     }
```

This is just a raw design, might need to be improved a lot, but something on these lines.

Comment: Please don't use a metaclass for something like this.  There are far to many of them out there already.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, using a metaclass results in quite verbose and somewhat opaque code doing something really simple.  In almost all cases, you can find a really simple and straight-forward solution by rearranging things a bit, resulting in far more readable code.  How to do this depends on many factors, and we would need a bit more context to suggest alternative designs.  And to be sure, there are valid use cases for metaclasses, but the vast majority of actual uses I've seen was overengineered in my opinion.

Comment: I know all the pros and cons of metaclass. If you haven't noticed, I  specified a one line solution as well. But IMHO, modifying class outside of class like that is not a too elegant solution, either. I think user need to find another workaround to generate mapping, but if he wants to store the result of class method only, then it is not too bad

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sorry I did not provide context (I would have imagined it was irrelevant here). I edited the question to explain a bit my intentions, which are motivated by clear code, and as importantly to me well structured code :)

Comment: Regarding your edit: I infered that "them" would refer to the collection of choices ? If that is the case, this collection is potentially generated by get_choices() at runtime, there is not necessarily a static list.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic you need to run is trivial then just putting the logic directly after the class is fine:

```
class Custom1:
    value = 1
    @classmethod
    def get_choices(cls):
        return [cls.value]
Custom1.mapping = {"key": Custom1.get_choices()}
```

If the logic is more complicated, and especially if needed by multiple classes, then a decorator could be useful. eg

```
def add_mapping_choices(cls):
    cls.mapping = {"key": cls.get_choices()}
    return cls

@add_mapping_choices
class Custom2:
    value = 2
    @classmethod
    def get_choices(cls):
        return [cls.value]
```